# "To ensure" vs. "To ensure that" + subject + predicate

Tags: relative-pronouns

Is any of these two sentences incorrect:

-(without that): "To ensure the voters are not influenced by mass-media, the campaign will end 7 days before the elections take place."

-(with that): "To ensure *that* the voters are not influenced by mass-media, the campaign will end 7 days before the elections take place."

Is the presence of *that* mandatory?

Comment: *That* is a relative pronoun, used for linking clauses, but which is frequently elided - as in *to ensure the voters are not influenced...*

Comment: The second is more correct than the first.

Comment: @WS2 This 'that' is the complementiser usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with both the previous commentators. WS2 is correct in saying that the relative pronoun here 'that' is frequently elided. I share Hot Licks's view that inclusion of 'that' is stylistically preferable.

Comment: This 'that' is the complementiser usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Google says that the complementiser concept is new (in the sense that "old-school" theory might have called it a conjunction instead). Is that accurate?